# Where clause throws error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Why does this code throw an error?

```
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(VarribleKeeper.MySQLConnectionString))
{
    {
        MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand();
        Command.Connection = cn;

        Command.CommandText = "UPDATE TeleworksStats SET Ja= ('" + JaTak +
            "') WHERE Brugernavn = " + VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn + "' AND Dato = " +
            DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "";
        cn.Open();
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Ryd op
        Command.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem error is thrown when I add the second where clause

Comment: This code looks vulnerable to `SQL Injection Exploits`. You should be using SQL Parameters.

Comment: int JaTak = 0;
        
            JaTak++;

Comment: @user3922197 uhm what do you mean with your comment?

Comment: Usually the best thing to do with Exception is to read it, what it says :).

Answer (score 3):

You missed one quote `'` after `Brugernavn =` and `Dato`:

```
Brugernavn = "... '" + VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn + "' AND Dato = '" +
             DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

Also I strongly recommend that you always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) like this:

```
Command.CommandText =
     "UPDATE TeleworksStats SET Ja = @Ja WHERE Brugernavn = @Brugernavn and ...";
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ja", JaTak);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brugernavn",  VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than AddWithValue. Check this: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: This is just test code so just ignore security

Comment: Brugernavn = '" + VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn + "' works!!!

but now my jatak++ does not work

Comment: It is supposed to + everytime button is clicked, problem is just that it does not + now :/?

Comment: And thanks user2946329!! I know it was a little thing but I just couldn't find the issue.

Comment: Post an example with a parameterized query, and you'll get a vote from me. There should never be any SQL injections in anyone's code. It's the responsibility of every developer to secure their work.

Comment: As i said, ignore security for now because this is just a test, i will make parameterized query after the code is working, its more easy for me

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: The where clauses are working, but why does jaTak++ not + when i add the second where cluse

Comment: You should never "`ignore security for now`." That is **very bad** practice, and you could end up leaving security holes all over the place.

Comment: As long as it is for testing, it does not matter rather i add the params now or in 10 mins

Comment: Parametrized queries, besides being more secure, have the advantage that you don't have to care about the right formatting of the parameters. This is especially true for dates, whose formatting differs among different SQL dialects.

Comment: Anyway, on topic, why does the Jatak++ works when it is only Command.CommandText = "UPDATE TeleworksStats SET Ja= ('" + JaTak + "') WHERE Brugernavn = " + VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn + "";

but does not work when i add the second where clause

Comment: Isn't this query right?

"UPDATE TeleworksStats SET Ja= ('" + JaTak + "') WHERE Brugernavn = '" + VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn + "' AND Dato = " + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "";

Comment: Because your date clause is wrong. You must place the date into single quotes. And it does not help to add an empty string `""` at the end. This has no effect at all. But all these problems would vanish if you were using parametrized queries. If you consider all these formatting problems, parametrized queries make your life easier. Use them!

Comment: I cant see why it does not add the value into the table when i add the second where clause?

Comment: @user3922197 ... it would be:`"UPDATE TeleworksStats SET Ja= ('" + JaTak + "') WHERE Brugernavn = '" + VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn + "' AND Dato = '" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"; ` But use parameters.

Comment: @user3922197  That code throws error

Comment: Olivier Jacot-Descombes could you give me an example please?

Comment: This is what this answer of user2946329 does.

Comment: @user3922197 sorry my bad, code works. So would anyone give me an example on how to use params? params are a little new to me, and its not in all vases i know how to use them

Comment: Olivier Jacot-Descombes i don't see params in that command line?

Comment: @user3922197...I show to you using parameters check my answer carefully please.

Comment: This is params isn't it? 

cmd.CommandText = "insert into TeleworksStats (Brugernavn,Dato) values (@i1,@i2)";

Comment: @user3922197...Yes it is. plus specifying the parameters value like this:`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i1", yourvaue);`

Comment: Okay, then I know what we are talking about. Thanks for all the answers, I am very thankfull for the help!!

Thanks everybody!

Comment: @user3922197...You're Welcome. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: Ohm, where do i find that check mark :)?

Comment: @user3922197...there is on check-mark beside of the answer just click on it.

Comment: I have been trying to find that for over an hour now! I promise you there is nothing, if you want to show me on TV i will happy watch it ;) but i cannot find it

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just forgetting `'` for the value of `Brugernavn` column and both single quotes for `Dato` column, I think you have more things to keep in mind.

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `Command` object as you did for your connection instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.
- Use [paramterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of string concatenation. This kind of codes are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Looks like you try to save your `DateTime` values with their string representations. **Do not do that!** If you wanna keep your `DateTime` values to your database, you need to pass them *directly*. Change your `Dato` column to [`DateTime` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

---

```
using(var cn = new MySqlConnection(VarribleKeeper.MySQLConnectionString))
using(var Command = cn.CreateCommand())
{
   Command.CommandText = @"UPDATE TeleworksStats SET Ja = @Ja 
                           WHERE Brugernavn = @Brugernavn  AND Dato = @Dato";
   Command.Parameters.Add("@Ja", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = JaTak;
   Command.Parameters.Add("@Ja", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = VarribleKeeper.Brugernavn;
   Command.Parameters.Add("@Ja", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today;
   // I assumed your column types. You should write proper column types instead.

   cn.Open();
   Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```